# A local variable named 'cmd' cannot be declared in this scope

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm learning C# from some videos. When trying to make a login webform, I get this error:

> Error CS0136: A local variable named 'cmd' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'cmd', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

I'm doing it on ASP.NET framework and using SQL Server as the database.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CONDOMINIO
{
    public partial class LOGIN : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void BtnIngresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            string conectar = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection sqlConectar = new SqlConnection(conectar);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INICIARS", sqlConectar)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

            cmd.Connection.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NOMBRE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = tbUsuario.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CONTRASENNA", SqlDbType.VarChar, 16).Value = tbPassword.Text;

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                //Agregamos una sesion de usuario
                Session["usuariologueado"] = tbUsuario.Text;
                Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Error de Usuario o Contraseña";
            }

            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the line of code that generates this error?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you declared cmd as a paremeter of the procedure and as a local variable. I guess you need to remove SqlCommand cmd from the protected void  BtnIngresar_Click(....) declaration

Comment: i'm using that to link the sql procedure to the webform, what should i do? remove it from the code or add that line somewhere else? thanks for the help

Comment: Button click handlers generally only have 2 parameters. Where do you wire up `BtnIngresar_Click`? What delegate do you use to declare the handler? Do you get an error on the line that declares `BtnIngresar_Click`? By the way, when you tell us you have an error, please point out which line the error points to (for example, with a comment).

Comment: As noted, the button click event code stub does NOT have 3 parameter's, and you can't change that, or try to add additional parameter's to the button click code stub. You have to remove the 3rd parameter from that button click. In fact, you want to let VS create that code stub for you, and not/never type in by hand that event stub code header.